# Passing user input to function with char* parameters

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, char, arguments

I get the following errors with my code.

> cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'char *
>
> no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const char *

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong in the menuSelection function below?  The point of it is if a user selects 1 from the menu options, the program gets user input (lastName, firstName, courseName, letterGrade) and passes it to the addRecord function but I think my data types are off.

Sorry for the long post.  The menuSelection function is towards the bottom right about the main() and head() functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

   
void GradeBook::addRecord(char* lastName, char* firstName, char* className, char letterGrade)
{
    StudentRecord* newRecord = new StudentRecord(lastName, firstName, className, letterGrade);
    if (_headRecord == NULL) {
        _headRecord = newRecord;
    } else { 
        int compare = _headRecord->compareTo(lastName, firstName);
        if (compare < 0) {
            // we insert before the first element
            newRecord->setNext(_headRecord);
            _headRecord = newRecord;
        } else {
            _headRecord->insert(newRecord);
        }
    }
}

  void menuSelection(int selection, GradeBook& gradeBook) {

    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string courseName;
    char letterGrade;

    switch(selection) {
        case 1: cin >> lastName.c_str() >> firstName.c_str() >> courseName.c_str() >> letterGrade;
                gradeBook.addRecord(lastName, firstName, courseName, letterGrade);
        case 4: gradeBook.read("students.txt");
                gradeBook.displayAllRecords();
                break; 
        case 5: gradeBook.write("students1.txt");
                break; 
        default: cout << "Enter a valid choice.\n"; 
        } 

        if (selection != 5) {
            displayMenu();
            cin >> selection; 
            menuSelection(selection, gradeBook);
        }
} 

void header() {
    cout << "STUDENT GRADEBOOK AND GPA CALCULATOR\n";
    cout << "=====================================\n";
}

void main()
{
    GradeBook gradeBook;

    int userSelection;
    header();
    displayMenu();
    cin >> userSelection; // get the user input for menu selection
    menuSelection(userSelection, gradeBook);
    
    char pause;

    std::cin >> pause;
}
```

Comment: I trimmed down the code so it was easier to read.

Comment: @Cat yeah, I tried to figure it out by using a snippet of similar code in my other post so people didn't get the notion that I want the work done for me.  Unfortunately I think I ended up confusing myself more so I went with the actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cin >> lastName.c_str() >> firstName.c_str() >> courseName.c_str()
    >> letterGrade;
```

I don't think you really want to do that. `c_str()` is to turn a regular C++ std::string into an old C-style "string" for use with functions that expect such a beast.

If you're trying to input a regular C++ string, you should change that to:

```
cin >> lastName >> firstName >> courseName >> letterGrade;
```

In fact, unless you're using the C library part of C++ (or third-party functions which explicitly requires C "strings"), you should never need to use a `char *` style of string. Embrace the language and use `std::string` as much as possible.

Comment: Not only you don't want to, you *can't* do that, `c_str` returns `const char*`.

Comment: and he needs to either change addRecord's definition or pass in .c_str() to addRecord too.

Comment: Cat: hence the error :-) Code Monkey: yes, updated the answer to cover this. C++ programmers should be _very_ circumspect if they ever find themselves using C-style strings. There are cases where they're needed but less than most people think.

Comment: Thanks but the function has parameter list of (char*, char*, char* char).  Maybe its my limited understanding of how pointers work but I used .c_str as someone said that would convert the string so it could be passed to char*....at least that the way I understood it.

Comment: @aWorkInProgress: yes, you can use `c_str()` if you want to pass a `std::string` to a function requiring `const char *`. What you _can't_ do is expect to use such a `const char *` with `cin >> blah`. It's `const` because you're not _allowed_ to change it.

Comment: Thanks paxdiablo!  I think I understand why I can't use that now, but I still don't quite grasp what I'd have to change to make it work.  I tried doing a replace all of char with string but that didn't work either.

Comment: I don't think I was able to implement it exactly the way you had in mind but using the c_str() I was able to get it to "work". :-/  I wish my professor was more accessible so I would have to go through this.

Comment: FYI what I did was this  char* lastName = _strdup(tempLastName.c_str()) with tempLastName being a string variable that holds the user input.

Answer (score 0):

First off, change all the parameters you're not modifying to `const char*`. Secondly, change all those parameters to be of type `const std::string&`. Thirdly, if the previous steps fail for some design reason, use `std::string::c_str()` which returns a `const char*` that lives untill the end of the function calls.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the following url: 
http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/string.html

in the section called C++ string.

You should basically convert your string to char*.

Comment: It's impossible to convert a `std::string` to a `char*` without explicitly copying the data array and appending a `\0`...